# Ideal generated by an element in a associative algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, ideals

I was looking at universal covering algebras for Lie algebras when I had across this question. To define a universal covering algebra $\mathfrak{U}$ of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ (over $\mathbb{F}$), we use the Tensor algebra $\mathfrak{I}$, which is an associative algebra. The formal definition of a tensor algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ is the set

$$\mathfrak{I} = \mathbb{F} \oplus \mathfrak{g} \oplus \left( \mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g} \right) \oplus \left( \mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g} \right) \cdots$$

To actually get the universal covering algebra, authors define an ideal $\mathscr{J}$ generated by an element

$$\left( 0, - \left[ x, y \right], x \otimes y - y \otimes x, 0, 0, \cdots \right)$$

where $x, y \in \mathfrak{g}$. Now, the computations that follow are easy to grasp. However, what I am still not able to understand (and actually see) is that what is $\mathscr{J}$? What will the general element of $\mathscr{J}$ look like?

Any insights here will be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that elements of $\mathscr{J}$ are linear combinations of elements of the form $a \cdot ( x\otimes y - y \otimes x - [x,y]) \cdot b$, with $x,y \in \mathfrak g$ and $a,b$ in the tensor algebra.

The very short answer is that you do not need to worry about elements of $\mathscr{J}$: you can forget about $\mathscr{J}$ once you have your envelopping algebra, satisfying the required universal property.

The less short answer is that given an element of the tensor algebra, knowing if it is inside $\mathscr J$ is not trivial. In fact, it is equivalent to asking whether this element is $0$ in the quotient $\mathfrak U$ or not. And answering this requires good knowledge of $\mathfrak U$. Such good knowledge is in fact provided by the Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt theorem. (Decompose the image in $\mathfrak U$ of your element on the PBW basis, and if all the coefficients are trivial, this image is $0$, and your element was in $\mathscr J$).